# Activity as dialog hide first activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I am working with activity as dialog. I want the dialog appear over the other activity but doesnt hide it.

This is my case, the dialog activity hide always my main activity.

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="tfg.marcos.coachtrain.views.DashBoardActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etDesdeFecha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:maxLength="40"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etHastaFecha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Hasta Fecha"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:maxLength="40"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etRepetirCada"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Repetir cada"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="40"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I add programmatically the theme becasuse if i add this into manifest.xml my app crashes:

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);
```

This shows me the dialog activity in the center of the screen and black around it.

Thanks!

Comment: `I am working with activity as dialog` - Any reason why a `Dialog` or `DialogFragment` can't be used?

Comment: because i want to add activity functionality and a dialog does not allow to me. Dialog is less functional i think

Comment: try this android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar">

Comment: i try with this and with all of dialog themes but doesnt work for me...

Comment: `because i want to add activity functionality` - in a `DialogFragment` you can call `getActivity()` like you can with a `Fragment` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have 2 activities on screen at the same time, that's why we have fragments. You should use a DialogFragment, from there you can get the Activity/context whenever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i do that with a fragmentdialog and into that fragment i include my own layout. Thanks